# Checking for a session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails app, if the user is trying to create a new account, and already has a session going (i.e. is logged in), I want to display a message that says "It looks like you already have an account".

To do this, I'm trying to check for a current session with the following code:

```
<% if session[:user_id]? %>
<div id="error_expanation">Seems like you already have an account with us.
  <% link_to "Sign in now", login %></div>
<% end %>
```

However, this code results in the following error:

```
compile error
/path/to/app/views/users/_form.html.erb:17: syntax error, unexpected ';'
');@output_buffer.safe_concat('     ...
   ^
/path/to/app/views/users/_form.html.erb:42: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting $end
```

I'm pretty sure is the 'session[:user_id]?' that's causing the problem, because if I replace it with something from another if statement, it works.

Any idea on what I need to fix to check for this?  Thanks!

Oh, and here's my sessions_controller.rb if it's needed:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    session[:return_to] = request.referer
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    if user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      session[:user_name] = user.name
      redirect_to admin_url
    else
      redirect_to login_url, :alert => "Invalid username / password combination"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to admin_url, notice => "You've successfully logged out."
  end  

end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest changing this line:

```
<% if session[:user_id]? %>
```

to

```
<% if session[:user_id] %>
```

That should fix the problem.  The cleaner solution would be to add a function call to your application controller like this:

```
class ApplicationController
  def user_is_logged_in?
    !!session[:user_id]
  end
end
```

Then you could do the following:

```
<% if user_is_logged_in? %>
```

Comment: Perfect solution, thanks. Still trying to get a hold of Ruby syntax, and the appropriate time to use things like question marks.

Comment: Question marks at the end of function calls are always part of the function definition and they are only a convention that indicates that the result of the function is boolean (true or false). Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly urge you to use something like Device for login logic, as it'll be more secure than any roll-your-own-code.  Then you can do something like:  `<%= dowhatever if user_signed_in? %>`

Comment: Just to add to jschorr's comment - Devise:  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Answer (score 1):

try `<% if session[:user_id] != nil %>`